# iCal STANDARD or DAYLIGHT error when already defined

Tags: icalendar

I have an iCal file that I am validating here

https://icalendar.org/validator.html?url=https://www.youreontime.com/calendar/syncstaff/d72e6edb-90da-4cc7-86c0-16fee6f3ad2e

It is giving an error **At least one STANDARD or DAYLIGHT property must be defined here near line # 4**

Here is the file which does have a time zone section at the top.

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//github.com/rianjs/ical.net//NONSGML ical.net 4.0//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:Australia/Sydney
X-LIC-LOCATION:Australia/Sydney
END:VTIMEZONE
BEGIN:VEVENT
ATTENDEE;CN=Adriane Bews;ROLE=REQ-PARTICIPANT:MAILTO:demo@youreontime.com
DESCRIPTION:Walter Jones (Ph 12456788)  Dry off. Staff Adriane Bews
DTEND;TZID=Australia/Sydney:20200215T133500
DTSTAMP:20200215T105625Z
DTSTART;TZID=Australia/Sydney:20200215T132000
SEQUENCE:0
STATUS:TENTATIVE
SUMMARY:Walter Jones Dry off
UID:yot-10025135
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Check out the "Example" header here: https://www.kanzaki.com/docs/ical/vtimezone.html  I think that's what it means by standard/daylight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Craig, Evan pointed you in the right direction.

What the message is saying is that "AT LEAST ONE STANDARD OR DAYLIGHT PROPERTY" must be defined IF one defines a VTIMEZONE.   A VTIMEZONE is a full definition of the timezone for the period of your events -ie if there is daylight saving, then one must define when there is a changeover, as per the example

```
  BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
  TZID:US-Eastern
  LAST-MODIFIED:19870101T000000Z
  BEGIN:STANDARD
  DTSTART:19971026T020000
  RDATE:19971026T020000
  TZOFFSETFROM:-0400
  TZOFFSETTO:-0500
  TZNAME:EST
  END:STANDARD
  BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
  DTSTART:19971026T020000
  RDATE:19970406T020000
  TZOFFSETFROM:-0500
  TZOFFSETTO:-0400
  TZNAME:EDT
  END:DAYLIGHT
  END:VTIMEZONE
```

Personally I think it would be great if one were able to assume that both one's own system and the receiving system had the latest Olson database timezone definitions and thus that any recurring events would end up with the same day & time.   However I supposed there is no guarantee of that, so the VTIMEZONE allows one to define the daylight saving changes etc that one's system is using.

Many systems may accept ics files without VTIMEZONES BUT they are supposed to be there and correctly defined.